# how to translate ngx-translate langs in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I'm using angular 2 and i'm using ngx-translate. 
i have two languages: ["en", "fa"] that i show them in the list below:

```
<md-select [(ngModel)]="currentLang" #langSelect="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="translate.use(currentLang);rtl(currentLang)">
    <md-option *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" [value]="lang" class="data_font"><span class="data_font">{{lang}}</span></md-option>
</md-select>
```

how can i translate the language's name( {{lang}} ) in the list?i tried {{lang | translate}} but it didn't work.

Comment: Why it didn't work? Was there any error in the console?

Comment: @mateusz-witkowski  i don't know! i translated the "fa" and "en" word in my i18n files but it doesn't work. i think it doesn't reconize how to translate {{lang}}

Comment: If there's no error in the console, then add code from the module where you import ngx-translate.

Comment: @mateusz-witkowski  well i translate many words in this component but i have problem in this part because it's an array